# Did I store the training loss and validation loss in a wrong way?

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, loss-function, mlp, overfitting-underfitting

Did I store the training loss and validation loss in a wrong way? Because the training loss is greater than the validation loss somehow.

```py
def train(dataloader, model, loss_fn, optimizer):
    size = len(dataloader.dataset)
    model.train()
    total_loss = 0
    for batch, (X, y) in enumerate(dataloader):
        X, y = X.to(device), y.to(device)

        # Compute prediction error
        pred = model(X)
        loss = loss_fn(pred, y)
        total_loss += loss.item()
        # Backpropagation
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        
        if batch % 100 == 0:
            loss, current = loss.item(), batch * len(X)
            #print(f"loss: {loss:>7f}  [{current:>5d}/{size:>5d}]")
    average_loss = total_loss / (batch + 1)
    train_losses.append(np.array(average_loss).mean())
```

```py
##Define a test function
def test(dataloader, model, loss_fn):
    size = len(dataloader.dataset)
    num_batches = len(dataloader)
    model.eval()
    test_loss, correct = 0, 0
    with torch.no_grad():
        for X, y in dataloader:
            X, y = X.to(device), y.to(device)
            pred = model(X)
            val_loss = loss_fn(pred, y).item()

            test_loss += loss_fn(pred, y).item()
            correct += (pred.argmax(1) == y).type(torch.float).sum().item()
            
    test_loss /= num_batches
    correct /= size
    accuracy = round(100*correct,2)
    val_losses.append(np.array(val_loss).mean())
    print(f"Test Error: \n Accuracy: {(100*correct):>0.1f}%, Avg loss: {test_loss:>8f} \n")
    return accuracy
```

```py
for t in range(epochs):
        print(f"Epoch {t+1}\n-------------------------------")
        train(train_dataloader, model, loss_fn, optimizer)
        test(test_dataloader, model, loss_fn)
    print("Done!")
    
    plt.plot(range(1, epochs+1), train_losses, label='Training Loss')
    plt.plot(range(1, epochs+1), val_losses, label='Validation Loss')
    plt.xlabel('Epoch')
    plt.ylabel('Loss')
    plt.title('Training and Validation Loss (lr = 0.001)')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
    train_losses = []
    val_losses = []
```

Here is the loss graph:

[image: Img]

I'm not sure if this is a hypeparameter issue or I store the training loss and validation loss inappropriately.